# How to write condition wise result providing query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a MySQL query that gives a condition wise result.

For example. I have a table with question, answer value, user chose value fields.

User can attend to answer that question many times.

```
qid     rightanz     wronganz
11         4             2
11         4             4
11         4             1
25         1             1

I want out put like this
qid     rightanz     wronganz
11          1            2   
25          1            0
```

I want to display how many times user provide right and wrong answers for that question?
How can I write a MySQL query for that?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can provide the table schema and how these columns are setup in your tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all questions

```
SELECT a.userId, q.qid
,SUM( CASE WHEN q.answer = a.answer THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS correct_answers
,SUM( CASE WHEN q.answer = a.answer THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS wrong_answers
FROM questions q
JOIN answers a ON q.qid = a.qid
GROUP BY a.userId, q.qid
```

For a specific question

```
SELECT a.userId
,SUM( CASE WHEN q.answer = a.answer THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS correct_answers
,SUM( CASE WHEN q.answer = a.answer THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS wrong_answers
FROM questions q
JOIN answers a ON q.qid = a.qid
WHERE q.qid = <question_id>
GROUP BY a.userId
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(IF(answer = 42, 1, 0)) AS correct_count, count(*) as total_count
FROM answers
WHERE user_id = 13
```

Supposing that `user_id` you want to inspect is 13 and correct answer is 42

Comment: Here's a tip: `SUM(IF(answer = 42, 1, 0))` is more elegantly expressed as `SUM(answer = 42)`